# EOF Exception at readutf in server side

Tags: java, sockets

I am Developing an Client Server socket application .Am reading Strings in server side for multiple clients inside run(override) method and I getting EOF Exception at readUTF. I Dont know why the error is comming  and how to rectify it.

```
    while (ss.compareTo("true") == 0) {
        System.out.println("Waiting for port " + port);
        sdc = soc.accept();

        cs[i] = sdc;
        System.out.println("Connected port " + cs[i]);

        DataInputStream dind = new DataInputStream(cs[i].getInputStream());
        DataOutputStream dout = new DataOutputStream(cs[i].getOutputStream());

        String password = dind.readUTF();
        String dept = dind.readUTF();
        uniqueName = dind.readUTF();
        String username = dind.readUTF();
        String ipaddress = dind.readUTF();
        String macaddress = dind.readUTF();
        String groupname = dind.readUTF();
    }
```

Comment: How are you writing these strings? If you aren't using writeUTF() it isn't going to work.

Comment: @EJP : Am using writeUTF() to write these strings

Comment: So post the code. You read more strings than you sent. Are you aware that readUTF() and friends throw EOFException at end of stream? Rather than returning null, for instance.